# ¿Por qué no me funciona el ejecutable?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

Estoy haciendo un programa de una calculadora haciendo uso de la librería tkinter, y quería crear un ejecutable para ver si funcionaba bien. Usando pyinstaller he ingresado el siguiente comando en el terminal.

```
pyinstaller mi_programa.py
```

En un primer momento todo parecía funcionar correctamente, se crearon todos los archivos que se tenían que crear. Pero cuando me meto en la carpeta generada *build* y abro el ejecutable que se genera, se abre el terminal y me aparece el siguiente error.

```
Gonzalo:~ gonzaloblanch$ /Users/gonzaloblanch/Desktop/Mis_proyectos/Python/CalAdvance2/build/CalAdvance2/CalAdvance2 ; exit;
[4416] Error loading Python lib '/Users/gonzaloblanch/Desktop/Mis_proyectos/Python/CalAdvance2/build/CalAdvance2/Python': dlopen: 
dlopen(/Users/gonzaloblanch/Desktop/Mis_proyectos/Python/CalAdvance2/build/CalAdvance2/Python, 10): image not found
logout
```

No se por que me aparece ese mensaje de *image not found* ya que no estoy usando ninguna imagen. Me gustaría saber como solucionarlo.

NOTA: Uso un MAC para programar

Añado el código que tengo hecho

```
import tkinter

ZEROERROR = "Error"

class Calculadora:
    def __init__(self, op1, op2, operation, result):
        self.op1 = op1
        self.op2 = op2
        self.operation = operation
        self.result = result
    def set_op1(self, num):
        self.op1 = float(num)
    def set_op2(self, num):
        self.op2 = float(num)
    def set_operation(self, opr):
        self.operation = opr
        console.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    def compute(self):
        self.result = True
        if self.operation == '+':
            return self.op1 + self.op2
        elif self.operation == '-':
            return self.op1 - self.op2
        elif self.operation == '*':
            return self.op1 * self.op2
        elif self.operation == '/':
            try:
                return self.op1 / self.op2
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                return ZEROERROR
    def insert(self, c):
        if self.result == True:
            console.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            console.insert(tkinter.END, c)
            self.result = False
        else:
            console.insert(tkinter.END, c)

cal = Calculadora(0,0,'', False)

#Ventana
ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("400x400")
ventana.title("CalAdvance")
#"Pantalla"
console = tkinter.Entry(ventana, font = "Helvetica 30")
console.place(x = 25, y = 30)
#Botones primera fila
boton7 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "7", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: cal.insert("7"))
boton8 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "8", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: cal.insert("8"))
boton9 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "9", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: cal.insert("9"))
boton_ac = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "AC", padx = 57, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.delete(0, tkinter.END))
#Botones segunda fila
boton4 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "4", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: cal.insert("4"))
boton5 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "5", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: cal.insert("5"))
boton6 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "6", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: cal.insert("6"))
boton_por = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "x", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: [cal.set_op1(console.get()), cal.set_operation('*')])
boton_entre = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "/", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: [cal.set_op1(console.get()), cal.set_operation('/')])
#Botones tercera fila
boton1 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "1", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: cal.insert("1"))
boton2 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "2", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: cal.insert("2"))
boton3 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "3", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: cal.insert("3"))
boton_sum = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "+", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: [cal.set_op1(console.get()), cal.set_operation('+')])
boton_rest = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "-", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: [cal.set_op1(console.get()), cal.set_operation('-')])
#Botones cuarta fila
boton0 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "0", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: cal.insert("0"))
boton_dot = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = ".", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: cal.insert("."))
boton_ans = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "Ans", padx = 18, pady = 20)
boton_igual = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "=", padx = 62, pady = 20, command = lambda: [cal.set_op2(console.get()), console.delete(0, tkinter.END), console.insert(tkinter.END, cal.compute())])
#Posicionando botones fila 1
boton7.place(x = 25, y = 100)
boton8.place(x = 100, y = 100)
boton9.place(x = 175, y = 100)
boton_ac.place(x = 250, y = 100)
#Posicionando botones fila 2
boton4.place(x = 25, y = 175)
boton5.place(x = 100, y = 175)
boton6.place(x = 175, y = 175)
boton_por.place(x = 250, y = 175)
boton_entre.place(x = 325, y = 175)
#Posicionando botones fila 3
boton1.place(x = 25, y = 250)
boton2.place(x = 100, y = 250)
boton3.place(x = 175, y = 250)
boton_sum.place(x = 250, y = 250)
boton_rest.place(x = 325, y = 250)
#Posicionando botones fila 4
boton0.place(x = 25, y = 325)
boton_dot.place(x = 100, y = 325)
boton_ans.place(x = 175, y = 325)
boton_igual.place(x = 250, y = 325)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola, Goblanch. Edita, por favor, la pregunta y añade el código del prorama que estás ejecutando para poder mirar con facilidad el problema.

Comment: Ve a la carpeta "dist", ahí encontrarás tu archivo ejecutable.

Comment: Tampoco funciona el ejecutable de la carpeta dist. Aparece el mismo error.

Comment: Seguramente es porque no tienes los archivos en la carpeta dis.